# CMake file(GLOB ...) doesn't warn when a directory does not exist. Is it by design?

Tags: cmake

I am using the file(GLOB ...) function in CMake to collect all files in a specific folder. Here's my code:

`file(GLOB mylist blablablabla )`

I noticed that if the specified folder (in this case, blablablabla) does not exist, CMake does not throw an error or warning; it simply treats it as an empty list. This can lead to subtle bugs that are hard to detect.

Is there a way to have CMake warn me or stop the script if the specified folder does not exist? I would like to have some feedback instead of silent failing in this scenario.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The CMake command [`file(GLOB ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob) returns a list of all files matching the globbing expression. If no files match, it returns an empty list. This is expected and documented behavior. So: yes, this is by design.

You can check for an empty list using a conditional expression like this:

```
file(GLOB mylist blablablabla)
if (NOT mylist)
    # issue a warning
    message(WARNING "File blablablabla does not exist!")
    # or abort altogether
    message(FATAL_ERROR "File blablablabla does not exist!")
endif (NOT mylist)
```

A side note: `blablablabla` is a globbing expression that matches only and exactly `"blablablabla"`. I assume this is just used as an example. To use a concrete directory name, you can use [`if (EXISTS blablablabla)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#exists).